# "subquery in select clause" showing same value for all the rows corresponding to Id

Tags: mysql, sql

`errorcount` in the below sql query is showing the same value for all the `Id` . I want a row-specific errorcount corresponding to `sreh2.Id` not the total count of `sreh1.statusId=19`

Result that I am getting is (109240 in errorcount column everywhere):-

```
Id          hubcount  errorcount
BC03262583  5         109240
BC03272635  6         109240
BC03281827  4         109240
```

By using this query:

```
select
  sreh2.Id,
  count(h.hubId) as hubcount,        
  (select count(sreh1.statusId)
   from `shipmentRouteEventHistory` sreh1 
   where sreh1.statusId=19
  ) as errorcount

FROM `shipmentRouteEventHistory` sreh2
  join `hub` h on sreh2.hubId = h.hubId
WHERE sreh2.statusId=3    
GROUP BY sre.Id
HAVING (count(h.hubId)>2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace

```
where sreh1.statusId=19
```

by

```
where sreh1.statusId=19
and sreh1.id = sreh2.id
```

Comment: When you use a subquery like this, you usually want a correlated subquery and the OP forgot to link the subquery (correlate it) to the outer query. I don't know about mysql, but in SQl server correlatled subqueries are very slow and should be replaced with joins instead. If your peformance is bad, consider joining to a derived table instead.